# CMake: create_symlink vs ln

Tags: cmake, symlink

I have a macro to create links E.g.

```
makeLink($BUILD_ROOT/lib somewhere/somelibrary.so makelinks)
```

The purpose of this is so that a completed build includes a directory structure analogous to a developers installation with *bin*, *include* & *lib* directories containing links to the actual products.

*However, the purpose is not relevant to my question which is about create_symlink and not a meta-question about whether links should be used for this or any other purpose.*

The macro can be implemented in several ways including:

```
macro(makeLink src dest target)
  add_custom_command(TARGET ${target} PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ln -sf ${src} ${dest} DEPENDS ${dest} COMMENT "mklink ${src} -> ${dest}")
endmacro()
```

or:

```
macro(makeLink src dest target)
 add_custom_command(TARGET ${target} PRE_BUILD
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ${src} ${dest} DEPENDS  ${dest} COMMENT "mklink ${src} -> ${dest}")
endmacro()
```

Now I understand the point of create_symlink is to be portable in case the platform doesn't understand links. However it seems to be functionally incomplete. There are several different use cases with *ln*

- create a link whether the source exists yet or not
- create a link only if the source exists
- overwrite an existing link or not

As far as I can see the cmake documentation under-specifies the behaviour (its actually: create the link if the destination doesn't exist and the source exists. Fail if the source doesn't exist)

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake.1.html

This seems possibly to confuse many users who think it ought to work according to one and only one of the possibly use cases. E.g.

https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14928
https://cmake.org/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=4418

*Given this why should anyone ever use create_symlink?
Wouldn't the sensible course be to incorporate support for all the common use cases (essentially by implementing a system portable wrapper to ln)?*
**Is there a semi-standard .cmake file for this somewhere?**

Also is cmake really doing a recursive call to fork itself when you use cmake -E or does the parser recognise it as a special case. I suspect the latter as seems very fast (granted creating links this way would still seem fast) but if that's so why the unnecessarily verbose syntax?

---

Note: I am not building the libraries as part of configure. *links* to libraries are created to support two things:

- linking programs that use the libraries in other sub-projects
- running tests that use the libraries

The libraries are not actually being built during the 'configure' stage. The links only need to be available just in time. This is part of a migration from a configure/make based build system to cmake/ninja. Its a largish project where a phased roll out of cmake is preferable to a big bang. It just so happens that in the existing system the links are made at configure time (though not used until build time).

Comment: For those who want to use this very useful macro, note a missing `$` in `{dest}` in the first version.

Answer (score 3):

Usually `create_symlink` is only used in the build directory to link to stuff mainly in the source directory. Given that and the required platform independence, everything is fine.

If you need more then `create_symlink` provides, there is a high chance you are using CMake in a way it is not intended or CMake is not the right tool for your task.
What CMake provides, as summarized by you with "*create the link if the destination doesn't exist and the source exists. Fail if the source doesn't exist*" is all you need. You know which file are created, so creating a link and not knowing whether this link already exists or whether the source exists should never happen. Why overwriting a link, when you just created it?

In your case, `add_custom_command` is just the right tool. Just replace `PRE_BUILD` by `POST_BUILD`.

Comment: Our configure stage creates lib & include build directories so that tests that are also run as part of the build can find them all in one place like a pseudo-installation.

Granted it is easy to misuse tools but it is also hubris for a tool to assume it knows best what its users needs might be.

Comment: Building libraries should not be part of configure. If you depend on libraries, create a sub_project. This can be included you get what you want. To me, your approach looks like not going the CMake way.

Comment: comment deleted as not enough space

Comment: For tests you can simply use target_link_libraries. I don't get why you hack around this feature. Or you can write a small macro which adds all the necessary libraries so you don't have to do it for every test.

Comment: This thread is distracting from my actual question. My question is to understand the motives behind the minimalist functionality of create_symlink and not to re-factor my actual build system as that task is already in hand.
I've updated the main question to try and reflect this better.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifying edit; I updated my answer accordingly.